# EU-SILC database about education and experience

Tags: stata

I am using EU-SILC database for 2008 for Greece. Firstly, I would like to use PE040 so as to create three dummies: `primeduc` for education on pre-primary AND primary school `seceduc` on lower secondary education +(upper) secondary + post-secondary non tertiary education and `tereduc` on 1st + 2nd tertiary stage.

Secondly, I would like to make a variable about working experience based on the idea `exper=age-educ-6` where `educ` I would like sth about the years (generally) spent in education.

Any ideas of which commands I should use on stata???

**What I've tried so far**
About stata syntax:

```
tabulate PE040, gen(educ)
gen primeduc=educ1+educ2
gen seceduc=educ3+educ4+educ5
gen tereduc=educ6
```

Having defined lnwage as =log(PY010N/(PL060+PL070)) and age as =2008-PB140, I've tried to regress and it takes only into account 191 obs.

Comment: Are you asking for help with the stata syntax or with the specific database schema? Either way, please tell us what you've tried so far and what results you get / why it's not working.

Comment: @Rup, mainly about stata syntax. Though, if you have any recommendations about database schema, please tell me.

Comment: I don't think there is a clear problem statement here that we can react to. (1) Part of this is specific to a dataset we can't see, although the problem is likely to be just missing values. See what messages you got when creating new variables. (2) The rest is too open-ended, more or less what else could I do?

Answer (score 1):

For your first question, I think you want a 0-1 indicator, equal to 1 if either of the indicated educational categories was recorded.

```
gen primeduc=educ1 | educ2
gen seceduc =educ3 |educ4 |educ5
```

The "|" stands for logical "or".  For example, `primeduc` will be 1 if `educ1` is 1  or `educ2` is 1.